# How to know which line the app crashed?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, version

I'm debugging an app in a real device and Eclipse. Certain feature makes it crash. There is no error on LogCat. I've managed to find which line it crashed in a similar situation by writting `Log.v` in many lines until I found which Log.v didn't show up. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Try to user another methods from Log class. somethings like i(...) or d(...)

Comment: if it crash there is an Log.e.
Make sure to enable debug on Device and to that you can see the Device in Logcat.

Comment: So - did you have any luck pinning this issue down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Debugging feature in Eclipse - it allows you to break the program flow on the occurrence of an exception (Run As -> Debug).

This will allow you to inspect the current local variables / call stack to further diagnose why the exception occurs.

p.s. One other method I use when hunting down an odd crash is to dump the full LogCat via the 'adb' CLI tool, and inspect it in a text editor. Sometimes the LogCat display in Eclipse can go a bit.. weird..especially if you've been connecting / disconnecting your device while developing (without closing Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Check Logcat filters (in Eclipse). Happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the 'debug' option on Eclipse, which made it not show the error. Detaching the debug after the crash, or just running the application from the begin (without the debug options) shows the error. To find the line, filter your LogCat by application, make the app crash and, on the red text that will appear, look for your package name. And the of the error (expection) itself is on the beginning of that text.